# Simple question on the genericity of induced representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, p-adic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL} \DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp} \DeclareMathOperator\Ind{Ind}$
Let $F$ be a $p$-adic field and $\Sp(2n)$ symplectic group over 2n dimensional symplectic space over $F$.

Let $B=TU$ be a minimal parabolic subgroup of $\Sp(2n)$ with maximal torus $T$. Let $\chi=(\chi_1,\cdots,\chi_n)$ be an unramified unitary character of $T(F)$ and $s=(s_1,\cdots,s_n)\in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Suppose that a normalized induced representation $\Ind_{B}^{\Sp(2n)}\chi^s$ have a unique unramified quotient $\pi$.

Then is there a sufficient condition on $s\in \mathbb{C}$ ensuring $\pi$ generic? Or if $\pi$ is generic, is there any necessary condition on $s\in \mathbb{C}$?

It might be affected by the condition on unitary character $\chi$.

Any comments will be appreciated!

(Here, the genericity of $\pi$ depends on the choice of additive character $\psi$ of $F$ and $a \in F^{\times}/(F^{\times})^2$. For example, define $\psi_a:U \mapsto \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ as $\psi_a(u)=\psi(u_{1,2}+\cdots +u_{n-1,n}+au_{n,n+1}).$ Then we can define the genericity of $\pi$ relative to $\psi_a$.)